# Data sent not being received in AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to create and AJAX call in Prestashop 1.6 and call the ajax.php file that will hold all ajax related code. My jQuery function that holds the $.ajax({}) is

```
    function setCustomCarrierMethod(method_id){
          if (method_id) {
            $.ajax({
              url: baseDir + '/modules/customcarrier/ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'ajax_function=set_customcarrier_method' + 'method_id=' + method_id,
                    dataType: 'json',
              success: function(json) {
                console.log("successfull request");
              },
              error: function(json) {
                alert(json.error);
                console.log("error in the request");
              }
            })
          }
        };
```

Then in the ajax.php file I've got:

```
<?php
session_start();
/* SSL Management */
$useSSL = true;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/smarty.config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/customcarrier.php');

$customcarrier = new CustomCarrier();

if (Tools::getValue('ajax_function') == 'set_customcarrier_method') {
    $customcarrier->setCustomCarrierMethod();
 }

?>
```

Any idea what am I getting wrong here will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't usually send the `data` like that but I think you need an `&` before `method_id=` for it to be transmitted as a second parameter. Is it not sending or not returning the response? As is I dont think `ajax_function` will equal `set_customcarrier_method`.

Comment: It is better to use object to send data like: `{ajax_function:'set_customcarrier_method' , method_id: method_id}`

Comment: did u refered j query library?

Comment: I all works now: I have taken under consideration @Qsprec 's answer and now I am sending a JSON.stringify(JSON object) as a data parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use & between two variables

```
 data: 'ajax_function=set_customcarrier_method' & 'method_id=' + method_id
```

.

```
function setCustomCarrierMethod(method_id){
          if (method_id) {
            $.ajax({
              url: baseDir + '/modules/customcarrier/ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'ajax_function=set_customcarrier_method' & 'method_id=' + method_id,
                    dataType: 'json',
              success: function(json) {
                console.log("successfull request");
              },
              error: function(json) {
                alert(json.error);
                console.log("error in the request");
              }
            });
          }
        }
```